# How to include sub directory in sitemap?

Tags: permalinks, urls, language, sitemap

I've been using All in One SEO Pack and Polylang two plugins on my wordpress site.

But the Polylang plugin for it needs to create another language's directory, so now **the sitemap feature from AIOSP** can not include the other language directory's posts.

Now my site has two languages, one is the main site `www.mysite.com` and the other is `www.mysite.com/cn` The sitemap can not detect what's behind the /cn thing, is there a way to include the content behind the /cn thing in the sitemap? Posts, pages, format...

Thanks!